# Javascript $resource problem with query string when using DELETE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a piece of JS to make an API call

```
.factory('DeleteResource', ['config', '$resource', function (config, $resource) {
        return $resource(config.myhost + '/my-path/:id', {
            id: '@id'
        }, {
            delete: {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }
        });
    }])
```

when I call this piece of code using POST, I make an API call to a url like this:

```
https://my-host/my-path/1
```

but, if I change POST to DELETE, I make a call to:

```
https://my-host/my-path?id=1
```

How can I make the call to DELETE using the first layout (no query string)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 .factory('DeleteResource', ['config', '$resource', function (config, $resource) {
    return $resource(config.myhost + '/my-path/:id').delete({
        id: '@id'
    });
}])
```

OR

```
 .factory('DeleteResource', ['config', '$resource', function (config, $resource) {
            return $resource(config.myhost + '/my-path/:id', {}, {
                delete: {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    params: { id: 'id' }
                }
            })
        }]);
```

Comment: none of this work unfortunately.